# After opening a laptop, how do you plug short ribbon cables back in?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, cable

I have a laptop which now requires an external keyboard. When I opened it (to clean the fan, it was overheating), the keyboard ribbon cable slid out of its socket and I cannot plug it back in. It is too short. When I hold both parts of the laptop close enough for the end of the ribbon cable to touch the connector, I cannot slide my hand in the gap to plug it in and to close the connector.

Is there a special tool to do this, or else what is the trick, please?

Comment: I have done this before.  I suggest getting the Hardware Maintenance Manual describing how it how it is done.

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing any details about the model. You might have to remove other components to be able to insert the cable.

Comment: It's a Dell Vostro 1000.

Answer (score 4):

There are typically two types of connectors:

One type can be opened by lifting the upper side like the lid of a piano:
[image]

The other type can be opened by pulling the inner part (here the white one) to the direction of the flex cable to release the tension of the contacts:
[image]

Open the locking, put the cable in position, move the locking part back and you're finished.

*Be careful and sensitive to not break anything.*

---

#### Update

As your ribbon to the keyboard connector is to short, I should ask, if you disassembled the system properly. Especially:

Is your keyboard still seated in the case or is it separate?

[image]

I think you didn't remove the keyboard but opened the case directly. So the metal plate of the case hinders you to unfold the whole ribbon.

How to properly remove your keyboard you can read in the [Owner's Manual for the DELL Vostro 1000](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-1000_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf), starting at page 101.

---

At notebooks, very often the keyboard is a separate module that can be disassembled without opening the whole case. And when you intend to open the wole case, one of the first things (after the battery) that should be removed is the keyboard.

After you've removed the screws (sometimes marked by keyboard pictogram) from the bottom of the case the keyboard usually isn't fixed anymore but only hooked in somehow.

Not at the DEL Vostro 1000. As can be seen in the picture, there are two screws at the upper edge of the keyboard, hidden by a cover.

Comment: This answer is correct, assuming that the OP is actually referring to an FPC (Flexible Printed Circuit) cable rather than a "*ribbon cable*". "*Ribbon cable*" would be terminated with an IDC connector, and simply mate to a header.

Comment: Thank you dodrg. Mine looks like the first picture. I know how to plug the ribbon cable back in. I have to slide it straight into the slot and then to push the handle down to lock the ribbon into place. My problem is that I cannot do this because the slot is right in the middle and the cable is so short that, when the end of the ribbon touches the slot, the 2 parts of the laptop are so close together that I cannot slide my hand between them to put the end of the ribbon in the slot and close the handle.

Comment: Updated the answer.